How is Tehilim Teach about The fear of G-d?
BH
Hi I read in Meam Loez correct me if I am wrong, that Rebbe would say that Psalms teaches about fear of G-d. How does it teach this specifically? & Is he talking about the pshat of Tehilim or the Sod teaches this?
